# Hover over span shows another span doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do css so that when i hover over a span another one shows up, but it wont work, is there something im doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<span class="text">Click me!</span>
<span class="tooltip">HI!</span>
```

```
.tooltip {
            width: 120px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border-color: #3e3e3e6c;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: relative;
            top: -8px;
            left: 27px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .text:hover + .tooltip-for-designation {
            display: block;
            color: red;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

Comment: @ Axel Ekenberg Your 2nd selector misses 2nd span's correct classnane. Instead,  it should be: .text:hover + .tooltip

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the span with class tooltip to hidden (display: none;) and your .text:hover + .tooltip-for-designation should be .text:hover + .tooltip to make it work.

See example:

```css
        .tooltip {
            display: none;
        
            width: 120px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border-color: #3e3e3e6c;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: relative;
            top: -8px;
            left: 27px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        

        .text:hover + .tooltip {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<span class="text">Click me!</span>
<span class="tooltip">HI!</span>
```

Comment: Hi, i fixed that problem but it still wont work, i am using .less but that wouldnt be the problem right?

Comment: That indeed shouldn't be a problem. I would advise you to check your LESS or HTML code for a typo and just test that your selector names are the correct ones.